# Tar daily files based on timestamp in name

Tags: bash

I have daily log files which are in the format:

```
abc-xyz.log.2019-10-01
abc-xyz.log.2019-10-02
abc-xyz.log.2019-10-03
```

What I'd like to do is have a bash script that tars and compresses each log file with it's associated timestamp and run in manually.

Could anyone point me in a good direction for this ?

so the output is :

```
abc-xyz.log.2019-10-01.tar.gz
abc-xyz.log.2019-10-02.tar.gz
abc-xyz.log.2019-10-03.tar.gz
```

So the script would read one file at a time and based on the timestamp in the name, would output the tared filename with the same timestamp.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Not much yet, just viewing and comparing other code.  Still learning.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Next time add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With xargs and GNU tar:

```
printf "%s\n" *[0-9] | xargs -I {} echo tar -czf {}.tar.gz {}
```

If output looks okay, remove `echo`.

---

See: `man xargs`

Comment: That's great Cyrus:  If I have other months in the folder like this:  abc-xyz.log.2019-09-01 and I just want to tar October,  then I could do this it seems:  ```printf "%s\n" abc-xyz.log.2019-10-{01..31} | xargs -I {}  tar -zcvf {}.tar.gz {}``` .  That seems like it works too.